# Write a recursion function to perform the fibonacci sequence up to the number passed in

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

This is the expected output:

```
Output for fib(5) => 
Iteration 0: 1
Iteration 1: 1
Iteration 2: 2
Iteration 3: 3
Iteration 4: 5
Iteration 5: 8
```

This was my output

```
def Iteration(xn):
    if xn <= 0:
        print("Iteration(0):1")
        return 1
    else:
        print(f'Iteration({xn}):{xn -1 + xn - 2}')
        return Iteration
```

```
Iteration(5)
```

Comment: There are a few ways to do this in Python using recursion, ranging from bad to terrible. Do you have any more specific instructions on which kind of recursive algorithm you are supposed to use?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the function, you need to call the function

Replace

```
return Iteration
```

with

```
return Iteration(xn-1) + Iteration(xn-2)
```

And change your if statements to

```
if xn == 0:
    return 0
elif xn == 1:
    return 1
```

This should fix your problem

So full code:

```
def Iteration(xn):
    if xn == 0:
        return 0
    elif xn == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return Iteration(xn - 1) + Iteration(xn - 2)
```

But I think to achieve the expected output you need another function.

```
def fib(n):
    for i in range(n + 1):
        print("Iteration({i}): {r}".format(i=i,r=Iteration(i+1)))
```

Output for `fib(5)`:

```
Iteration(0): 1
Iteration(1): 1
Iteration(2): 2
Iteration(3): 3
Iteration(4): 5
Iteration(5): 8
```

Comment: So both the above codes together?

Comment: @JimTurner the functions `fib(n)` and `Iteration(xn)` produce with `fib(5)` the output at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This stanza:

```
return Iteration
```

Returns a function (the function `Iteration`), not a value. You want to instead *evaluate* the `Iteration` function:

```
return Iteration(xn - 1) + Iteration(xn - 2)
```

This will return the value calculated by the iterative step.